# xCode 6.3.1 Missing references while running on simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am working on xCode 6.3.1, everything is working fine while debugging on device iPhone 5s iOS 8.3 but when I disconnect device and try to test application with simulator there are hundreds of errors about "Missing references" for many framworks (with any simulators iOS8+)

I tried to remove missing references and add again in "Build Phase" but no use.
Furthermore, I am having pods setup but missing references are from project of course. It was working fine before update to Xcode 6.3.1, here is one example error: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllGroups". Addressbook is not some framwork which should only supported for device and not for simulator.

It is working fine with device, I uploaded Archive to app store, there was no issue either. Only with simulator.

Comment: This sounds like the framework doesn't include support for the iOS Simulator.  You need to understand that each binary/library in iOS and OSX can be bundled to support multiple CPU architectures; for iOS this is arm7/arm64, but for iOS Simulator this is i386/x86_64.  If the framework is not build with iOS Simulator support the app will not compile for iOS Simulator.

Comment: Check is it build able on device or not? some framework doesn't support for the iOS Simulator.

Comment: @trojanfoe: It was working fine before update to Xcode 6.3.1, here is one example: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllGroups".

Addressbook is not some framwork which should only supported for device and not for simulator.

Comment: @aBilal17: It is working fine with device, I uploaded Archive to app store, there was no issue either. Only with simulator.

Comment: @AiOsN OK, well that's information that should have been part of the original question.

Comment: @trojanfoe: Ok i will add this in question now, is there any solution, what you think could possible problem can be, as I have done everything I know, re-add references, clean project, check project file contents, delete and re-download repo, restart Xcode and machine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution, may be could help someone else, for me it was iPhone SDK location path as follows:

Build Settings>Framework search paths>iPhoneOS.platforms

I did not correct this path, I Just delete path and its working on simulator now.

Furthermore, Archive and debugging on device work perfect as well.

[image]